# spectral integral

Tags: functional-analysis, integration, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am learning spectral integration for my summer. I am stuck at a point.

Having got hold of a spectral measure, we define the spectral integral of a simple function as usual and then approximate any bounded measurable function in uniform norm by a sequence of simple functions and then the integral of the bounded measurable function is defined as the limit of the sequence of integrals of the approximating simple functions (that this sequence converges can be shown).

Then for the unbounded functions, we approximate pointwise by bounded functions specifically if $f$ is an unbounded measurable function on a measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ then define

$$ M_{n} = \{t \in X \,| \quad |f(t)| \leq n \} $$

and define

$$ f_{n} = f\chi_{M_{n}}.$$

Then we can define the integral of $f$ at a vector $x$ as

$$ I(f)x = \lim_{n}I(f_{n})x $$

for all those $x$ for which the above limit exists.

I understand that if the function is bounded, then the integral operator so obtained is bounded and its norm is equal to the sup-norm of the function.

**However, I cannot see that if the integral of the function is bounded, then the function should be essentially bounded. Could some one give me any leads?**

I am following Schmudgen's "Unbounded Self-Adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space", but I am not able to follow the proof he gives. Also, the proof seems a little too complicated.

Comment: SO exactly what are you trying to prove? That $$I(f)\ \text{is a bounded operator} \Rightarrow f \text{ is a bounded function},$$ where $I$ is integration against the spectral measure associated to an unbounded self-adjoint operator, right? (P.S.: I am asking because your question is not very clear. The implication above is *false*)

Comment: spectral measure is a generic spectral measure, not necessarily coming from a self-adjoint operator. And you say that it is false? Could you give a counter-example?

Comment: (Any spectral measure comes from some self-adjoint operator.) To prove that the claim is false take any finite-dimensional operator. The spectral measure is then reduced to a finite sum of Dirac deltas. You can integrate a lot of unbounded functions against Dirac deltas and the result is bounded. Let me know if I was not sufficiently clear.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro My functions are almost everywhere finite-valued. Even then it is false? Look at Theorem 13.25 in Rudin's Functional Analysis.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what's going on. You speak of "bounded" functions meaning "essentially bounded" functions (that is, more or less, "bounded up to sets of measure zero" - precise definition on Rudin's book, Definition 12.20). Here the measure is the resolution of the identity $E$ (to use Rudin's notations). You might want to add a remark to the question to prevent future misunderstandings of this kind.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being sloppy. I meant essentially bounded functions